# Pull refresh of RefreshView not working when contains cards:CarouselView

Tags: xamarin.forms, pull-to-refresh, cardview

I have implemented cardview inside of refreshview. RefreshView pullrefresh not working.
Using library https://github.com/AndreiMisiukevich/CardView/blob/master/docs/CardsView.md/

```xml
       <RefreshView x:DataType="local:ItemsViewModel" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"  Command="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">

                 <!--https://github.com/AndreiMisiukevich/CardView/blob/master/docs/CardsView.md-->
              <cards:CarouselView  x:Name="ItemsListView" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                IsHorizontalOrientation="False"
                ItemsSource="{Binding RootData}"
                IsCyclical="False"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RootSelector}" >     

              </cards:CarouselView>  

       </RefreshView>
```